# Calling API Request Inside Laravel Observer

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Hello I need To run an API Request after the model is updated so I have used Laravel observer

the API is tested in the controller Work fine but in the observer, something is wrong without any error log happening

```
public function updated(CampaignInfluencer $campaignInfluencer)
{
    $this->handleCampaignInfluencerSaving($campaignInfluencer);
    
$http = new Client();


 $response = $http->request('POST', $url, [
    'headers' => [
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
    ],
 ]);
   
}
```

Can't i Call API From Laravel Observer  ?

Comment: Please, explain what is wrong

Comment: And are you shure that the observer is triggered?

Comment: You can make API from Observers. Check that you have registered the observer for your model in EventServiceProvider in the boot method. If you then still don't get any errors you should debug, that you code is called. Right now you are ignoring the $response. Try to check if the $response has a status code of 200 or not. If not log it as warning or error.

Comment: Is that exact code from controller where it worked?